# Insert Autocomplete textbox inside listview WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, autocompletebox

I want to insert autocomplete textboxes inside listview control in WPF.

Comment: do you have any code which you have tried

Comment: no i did not get any thing after searching ...

Comment: there are many examples which explain autocomplete textbox but i did'nt find any thing which explain how to insert autocomplete textbox inside listview.

Comment: Use `ItemTemplate` property.

Answer (score 0):

well I downloaded a premade auto complete textbox from nugget called "WpfControls.AutoCompleteTextBox"
here's the code to add it:

```
    private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WpfControls.AutoCompleteTextBox TestTextBox = new WpfControls.AutoCompleteTextBox();
        listView.Items.Add(TestTextBox);
    }
```